# How to make activity wait befor execute next command in android

Tags: android, wait

I want the main activity to wait some time before excuting the next command.
I tried the wait method on the activity but it doesnt work well..
what should i do?

thx in advance

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's very unclear what you're trying to actually accomplish. What's your "command" and why would you delay it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post a Runnable, like so:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        // Execute your delayed code
    }
};
```

...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int millisDelay = 5000;
handler.postDelayed(task, millisDelay);
```

The code will execute 5 seconds after the `postDelayed` call.

Comment: And explanation why? For example why author should use Handler? and not for example Service?

Comment: A service is totally overkill for his requirements as I understand them. Handlers are perfect for executing small tasks after a delay.

Comment: This was only example...I wanted to say that author is most likely beginner and you are posted solution and he doesnt know why he should use it, you just added code - "I would use" but for what you would use it? and why?

Comment: Why don't we wait for him to ask? Your concern is noted however, thank you :)

Comment: So usually if im posting solution, i also will add explanation why author should use my solution or solution provided by another person, its better for author to understand why this snippet of code he have to use or can't use.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to use StackExchange, I'll try and answer like you do from now on.

Comment: explanation would be appreciated.@KenWolf

Comment: What's your question? @LeonNicetomeetya

Comment: @LeonNicetomeetya here's a good overview: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: @KenWolf thx a lot!Would u Define the Runnable in the class which has the method you want to execute?and initialize in the method itself?(as putting the hole method code in the Run section)